# How to reduce or eliminate the flavor of orange in a stew?

Tags: flavor, stews, oranges

I made a stew that required a couple of slices of orange, and it now has a strong orange flavor. It was cooking for over 3 hours and the orange skin was even dissolved. Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've normally found that acid (vinegar) and bitterness (sharp herbs perhaps) can lower the intensity of the sweetness of orange. I also think that a slightly bitter herb like rosemary or sage would meld nicely with the orange, burying the flavor a bit. It might already be a little bitter from the pith of the orange.

Answer (score 1):

Skin (peal) can impart a lot of flavor.    Garlic and onion will knock it down some.

Salt will knock it down some but I pretty much never add salt for health reasons.